# Dropzonejs with ng-view of angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dropzone.js, ng-view

I have particular problem with making dropzonejs working with ng-view directive:

Below is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="Museum">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Login page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="framework/bootstrap-3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="framework/angular-1.3.0-beta.19/angular.js"></script>
<script src="framework/angular-1.3.0-beta.19/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="framework/angular-1.3.0-beta.19/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="framework/angularUI-0.11.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js"></script>
<script src="framework/dropzone-3.10.2/dropzone.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="framework/dropzone-3.10.2/css/dropzone.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
<script src="app.js"></script>
<body>

   <div ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

My app.js:

```
 var app = angular.module('Museum', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngResource',      'ngRoute']).config(['$resourceProvider', function ($resourceProvider) {
// Don't strip trailing slashes from calculated URLs
$resourceProvider.defaults.stripTrailingSlashes = false;
}]).config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
    when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'components/login/login.html',
        controller: 'Login',
        css: 'components/login/css/login.css'
    })
    .when('/create', {
        templateUrl: 'components/inventory/create.html',
        controller: 'Add'
    }
);
```

}]);

And my create.html page with dropzonejs:

```
<form action="/upload" class="dropzone" id="file-dropzone"></form>
```

It all works fine when I put dropzone form directly in index.html but when I route to create.html with dropzonjs using ng-view directive it does now work. Dropzone form is not process, e.g class is not "dropzone ng-pristine ng-valid dz-clickable" but "dropzone ng-pristine ng-valid", no div with message is added, etc.

Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't get the drop in method to work nicely, and indeed. it seems its only when there is a view involved.

Make sure that **dropzone.js** is loaded, and that the area/div you are dropping onto has an id.

on my view, I have an `ng-init="initDropZone()"` attribute. doesn't matter where really, just has to be in the view template.

Then, in my controller :

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-dropzone",{url:'/myuploadscript.php', createImageThumbnails:false});
//I have used a success event so i can use the result from the save.
myDropzone.on("success", function(file,response) {
    //remove the thumbnail that gets chucked on the dropzone element
    myDropzone.removeAllFiles(true);
    //result is treated as a string, I've responded in json from my
    //upload script on the server.
    //{success:true, newfile:'myfilepath.jpg'}
    result = JSON.parse(response);
    if (result.success)
    {
        //I originally tried using the angular ng-src bound var,
        //shown as model.data.Image (using model instead of $scope)
        model.data.Image = "//:0";
        model.data.Image = result.newFile;
        //but this was outright ignored. like no change.
        //accepted defeat and just jqlite hacking to manually change
        //the source of the img element.
        $('#mainImg').attr("src", "/" + result.newFile);
    }
});
```

This will change the image source immediately once the file has been uploaded and the server responds. I wish angular was more friendly and someone will no doubt point out a better solution, so if this gets a response out of a guru then we both win. otherwise, this will do as you are trying to do.

Oh and just confirming, there is no dropzone class/element defined on the html, its just a div that has an id of `my-dropzone`

Comment: also, the `myDropzone.removeAllFiles(true);` isnt to remove the thumbnail alone, thats taken care with the option passed to the dropdown init object, but the name and icons etc are still left behind when I've tried it. This removes them. And removing them on any other event stops the upload process so was stuck with a flicker. There are probably more graceful ways of doing it but I've only used angular for a couple of months now.